# Delete all folders with matching criteria and their content

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to know how to delete a folder using MS Access VBA.

The structure looks like this:

```
       MainFolder
          - Africa 2014.04
          - Europe 2014.05
          - USA 2014.06
```

I need to search for all folders in MainFolder, find the folders which contain 2014.04 and delete them with all the files.

UPDATE 25-May-2014:

I really do not know what really was not clear but thank you anyhow for ganging up on me today. And what I got for an answer is exactly what I need it : (. I will try next time to not post anymore.

Update 26-May-2014:

I`m sorry one more time for all the misunderstandings, but all the time when I do write an something in the site I see edit suggestion is in progress. So I thought if I write something with less words would not give hard time to someone to fix my grammars.

Here is what I wanted to achieve.

```
     Function DeleteSubfoldersIn(ByVal sDir)

      Dim inFS As New FileSystemObject
      Dim inDir
      Dim inSub
      Dim strDateNow As String
      Dim strASub As String
      Dim strDiffDate As String

      strDateNow = Format(Date - 90, "yyyy.mm")
      Set inDir = inFS.GetFolder(sDir)
      For Each inSub In inDir.SubFolders
      DeleteSubfoldersIn inSub.Path
      strASub = Right(inSub.Path, 7)
      If strASub = strDateNow Then
      If Dir(inSub.Path & "\*.*") <> "" Then
      Kill inSub.Path & "\*.*"
      End If
      RmDir inSub.Path
      End If
      Next inSub
      End Function
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dir` to search for the folders.

Use `Kill` to delete all the files in the folder; You may need recursion if there are subfolders.

Use `RmDir` to delete the folder.

Basic structure of code:

```
strFolderName = Dir("C:\MainFolder\*2014.04*", vbDirectory)

Do While strFolderName <> ""
    Do While... 'loop for deleting files
        Kill...
        ...
    Loop
    RmDir strFolderName
    strFolderName = Dir
Loop
```